# MySQL: How to trim varying characters in strings so the formats match?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a column with differing records that I want modified so that the formats match:

This is what it looks like currently:

```
col                           
UPL_2019_NF_R1_01_COST.csv      
UPL_2019_NF_R2_01_COST.csv     
UPL_2019_NF_R1_01_DRG.csv      
2019_ICF_R8_01.xlsx            
2020_ICF_R8_02.xlsx
```

And this is what I want it to look like:

```
col1                
2019_NF_R1_01       
2019_NF_R2_01       
2019_NF_R1_01       
2019_ICF_R8_01      
2020_ICF_R8_02
```

I'm trying to get the column to begin with the year and have only 3 underscores.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the point of having two columns if they're always the same?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I actually want to modify columns from two separate tables. Once I get the formats to match, I want to perform a JOIN on them. I just edited the question now.

Comment: the title no longer describes the question after the edit. There's nothing to match with.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0 you can use `regexp_substr` to extract a substring that matches a given regex.

The following expression matches on 4 consecutive digits followed by 3 groups of characters separated by underscores ; the dot character is an alternative stopper for the last group, so we don’t swallow the extension :

```
regexp_substr(
    col1, 
    '\\d{4}_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^._]+'
)
```

We can factor out the repeating part :

```
regexp_substr(
    col1,
    '\\d{4}(_[^_]+){2}_[^._]+'
)
```

And if we are sure they the dot character never appears within the wanted string :

```
regexp_substr(
    col1,
    '\\d{4}(_[^._]+){3}'
)
```

Comment: The last one should be `[^_.]+` so it doesn't include the extension.

Comment: I'm working with MySQL 5.6.10. I'm assuming `regexp_substr` won't work on this version right? If not, is there anything else I could do?

Comment: @miquiztli_: that kind of string operation will be tedious in pre-8.0 versions.  And MySQL 5.6 reached EOL last year…